How to prove that $ \underset{\varDelta x\rightarrow 0}{\lim}\frac{\left| MN \right|}{\overset{\frown}{MN}} $
In the derivation of the arc differential formula, why is the limit of the ratio of the length of the line segment between two points to the length of the arc considered to be 1: $$
\underset{\varDelta x\rightarrow 0}{\lim}\frac{\left| MN \right|}{\overset{\frown}{MN}}
$$
How can this be proved?
What I've learnt so far is that the limit holds when the function $y = f(x)$ is smooth, are there weaker conditions under which the limit also holds? How can I prove it?

Most functions do not admit a notion of an arclength, the closest one can get to arclength in general is the idea of total variation, which is finite for bounded variation functions (search up BV spaces). BV functions on the real line in fact admit a derivative almost everywhere and so your usual arclength integral is defined.

For continuously differentiable functions I think this holds true, but for anything else I think you can already find counterexamples.
